# How can the Racket web server be used without managing continuations?

Tags: webserver, racket

I am trying to develop a simple web API for testing using Racket's web server. The requirements are:

1. Respond to port requests with a callback in a new thread.
2. Read the header values and POST data
3. Write response headers and content to the port.

I do not want to engage the complexity of stateful versus stateless servlets. Essentially I want to avoid the overhead of managing continuations.

Answer (score 0):

- By avoiding calls to any `send/...` function other than `send/back` the [`serve/servlet`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/run.html?q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fservlet-env..rkt%29._serve%2Fservlet%29%29)  can be used without invoking continuation handling.
- Calling `(serve/servlet start #:manager web-server/managers/non ...)` will cause an error if there is an attempt to use continuations.
- Custom headers/content can be created using a "raw" [`response`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/http.html?q=response%20&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fhttp%2Fresponse-structs..rkt%29._response%29%29) structure.

Alternatively, using [`serve\launch\wait`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/web-server.html?q=ch/wa&q=patch-lift&q=raw&q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fservlet-dispatch..rkt%29._serve%2Flaunch%2Fwait%29%29) with a dispatcher using [`web-server/dispatchers/dispatch-lift`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/dispatch-lift.html?q=patch-lift&q=raw&q=serve/ser&q=serve/ser&q=%23%3Amanager) is possible. Raw data may even be written directly to the port.

Reference: [Original discussion](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-July/063242.html) on Racket discussion list.